# Error running a quantstrat analysis

Tags: r, quantstrat

I'm stuck with the following analysis:

```
library(quantstrat)

stock_size = 200
tickers = c("XOM", "MCD")
init.date = as.Date("2008-01-01")

usd = "USD"
currency(usd)
for(ticker in tickers){ 
  stock(ticker, currency=usd, multiplier = 1)
}

options("getSymbols.warning4.0"=FALSE)
getSymbols(tickers,from=init.date,to.assign=TRUE)

suppressWarnings(rm(strat, port, acct, ords))

port.name <- "MyPort"
port <- initPortf(port.name,tickers,initDate=init.date)
acct.name <- "MyAcct"
acct <- initAcct(acct.name,portfolios=port.name, initDate=init.date, initEq=35000)
ords <- initOrders(portfolio=port.name,initDate=init.date)

strat.name <- "MyStrat"
strat<- strategy(strat.name)
strat<- add.indicator(strategy = strat, name = "SMA", arguments = list(x=quote(Ad(mktdata)), n=20),label= "ma20" )
strat<- add.indicator(strategy = strat, name = "SMA", arguments = list(x=quote(Ad(mktdata)), n=50),label= "ma50")

strat<- add.signal(strat, name="sigCrossover", arguments = list(columns=c("ma20","ma50"), relationship="gte"), label="ma20.gt.ma50")
strat<- add.signal(strat, name="sigCrossover", arguments = list(column=c("ma20","ma50"), relationship="lt"), label="ma20.lt.ma50")

strat<- add.rule(strategy = strat,name='ruleSignal', arguments = list(sigcol="ma20.gt.ma50", sigval=TRUE, orderqty=stock_size, ordertype='market', orderside='long', pricemethod='market'), type='enter', path.dep=TRUE)
strat<- add.rule(strategy = strat,name='ruleSignal', arguments = list(sigcol="ma20.lt.ma50", sigval=TRUE, orderqty='all', 
ordertype='market', orderside='long', pricemethod='market'), type='exit', path.dep=TRUE)

out<-try(applyStrategy(strategy=strat, portfolios=port.name))
charts.PerformanceSummary()
```

because I got this couple of errors:

```
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("XOM.Adjusted.SMA.50", "XOM.Adjusted.SMA.20.ma20.SMA.50" : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
Error in inherits(x, "xts") : argument "R" is missing, with no default
```

Can anyone help me to find what's wrong?

Comment: This site isn't a place for "Find my errors" - you need to have a specific programming related question.

Comment: @SeñorO IMO, this is a model question.  It gives a concise, reproducible example that looks almost identical to a demo that comes with the package, but this code gives an error and it isn't obvious where it comes from since it occurs somewhere in the quantstrat code.  SO is exactly the place to come to ask for help figuring out why an error is occurring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the current version of TTR, the names of the columns returned by the MA-indicators are prefixed by the name of the input column. Eg. *SMA(MCD.Adjusted, n=20)* returns a column named *MCD.Adjusted.SMA.20*.

*Ad()* will return all column names that match the string *Adjusted*.

By the time your second SMA-indicator gets called, *Ad()* will match 2 column names (the original *MCD.Adjusted* column plus the output column for the first indicator *MCD.Adjusted.SMA.20*). This results in a dimension error, because in the current implementation SMA() can only handle one input column at the time.

The solution is to pass only the first match, using *quote(Ad(mktdata)[,1])* in your argument list.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jan Humme, now the script proceeds until line 37 where there's `charts.PerformanceSummary()`. It shows: `Error in inherits(x, "xts") : argument "R" is missing, with no default`. Is there a way to get rid of this last error?

Comment: @user601423 you cannot call `charts.PerformanceSummary` with no arguments.  `R` is a required argument.  See `?charts.PerformanceSummary`